# Defining multiplication over functions in Python?

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to define multiplication over functions in Python, in pseudocode this is:

This should return a function in x, given f(x), g(x)

```
multiply_two_functions((f(x), g(x)) = f(x) * g(x)
```

I can do this in Haskell like so:

```
mult :: (Num b) => (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b)  
mult f g = h
    where h x = (f x) * (g x)
```

You might ask why I'd want to do this - I have a list of functions [f], and I want to reduce these with multiplication. Again, in Haskell:

```
reduce_mult list = foldl mult 1 list
```

Edit: How I'm using it in python, for completeness:

```
def prod_reduce(f_list):
    def identity(x):
        return 1
    def f_mult(f, g):
        def multiplied(x):
            return f(x) * g(x)
        return multiplied
    prod = identity
    for f in f_list:
        prod = f_mult(prod, f)
    return prod
```

Does anyone have any tips for the Python implementation?

Comment: If you use callable classes (i.e. implement [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__)) instead of regular functions, you can define whatever multiplication behaviour you want ( see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). Or are you asking how to write the `multiply_two_functions` function? Could you give an example of how you'd use it in Python, for those of us unfamiliar with [tag:haskell]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the OP with an example of how I used it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just write a function that returns a new function that returns the product of the results of the other functions:

```
def multiply_funcs(f, g):
    def multiplied(x):
        return f(x) * g(x)
    return multiplied
```

Comment: @Leon note that this only works for functions that take a single argument

Comment: I see that your answer is also correct (of course), but much more general than I need. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 6):

If you are asking how to implement a function to create a new function that multiples the results from the target functions, it would look something like:

```
def multiply_two_functions(f, g):
    """Return a new function for e.g. h(x) == f(x) * g(x)."""
    def h(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs) * g(*args, **kwargs)
    return h
```

Note the use of `*args, **kwargs` to handle any positional and keyword arguments (see e.g. [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)); the only limitation is that any pair `f` and `g` must be able to handle the same arguments that will be passed to `h`. In use:

```
>>> def f(x):
    return x + 1

>>> def g(x):
    return 2 * x

>>> h = multiply_two_functions(f, g)
>>> h(5)
60
```

---

If you want to actually make `h = f * g` work, you would have to implement a class with `__call__` and `__mul__`:

```
class Func(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
            return self(*args, **kwargs) * other(*args, **kwargs)
        return Func(new_func)
```

This can be used as follows:

```
>>> f = Func(lambda x: x + 1)
>>> g = Func(lambda x: 2 * x)
>>> h = f * g
>>> h(5)
60
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do almost the same thing in Python: return a lambda that multiplies the two functions.

```
def multiply_two_functions(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(x) * g(x)
```

Test:

```
def a(x):
    return 2 * x

aa = multiply_two_functions(a, a)
print(aa(0), aa(1), aa(2))
```

Output:

```
(0, 4, 16)
```

Comment: Thanks - clear response (I can't believe I didn't see that, but never really thought of returning an anonymous function in Python)